# I want to replace a result from a Query with my own value of choice

Tags: sql, db2

I'm using QMF from IBM DB2 and I have a simple query

```
SELECT * 
FROM COUNTRYTABLE
```

Instead of giving names like US, Germany, I get a result like 123, 456, because we're using Country codes.

There's not a single table where you would get the name "Germany", so I cannot join to be able to obtain the result I want.

Is there a way to switch/replace the value of 123 to Germany? I know we can use this for Columns names with Country as Countries, but I'm not sure for results from a query.

I do not have administrative privileges, I'm just a simple user, so no fancy stuff for me.

I tried searching the web, but I didn't even know how to phrase the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the table, but.. if you lack access you can use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN country_Code=123 THEN 'Germany'
        WHEN country_Code =124 THEN 'Spain'
        ELSE country_Code
        END as Country,
    Column2,
    Column3
FROM CountryTable;
```

I can't recall if CTE's in DB2 allow SELECTS without a FROM, but if they do you may also consider making a CTE and joining to that as another option:

```
WITH country AS
(
    SELECT 123 as country_code, CAST('germany' as varchar(50)) as country_name
    UNION ALL SELECT 124, 'Spain'
    UNION ALL SELECT 125, 'Portugal'
)
SELECT
    country.country_name,
    countryTable.column2,
    countryTable.column3
FROM
    countryTable
    LEFT OUTER JOIN country 
        ON countryTable.country_code = country.country_code;
```

Comment: This one worked. I Will try the decode one too, thanks, wasn't aware of CASE sintax

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would need a look up table

e.g. COUNTRY

```
CODE | COUNTRY
123  | GERMANY
124  | SPAIN
```

and so forth.

Then you can join like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM COUNTRYTABLE
 JOIN COUNTRY ON COUNTRY_CODE = CODE
```

Comment: He said he's a user without admin privileges so creating a lookup table is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DECODE at is it meant to do exactly that.

```
SELECT
    DECODE(COUNTRY_CODE,
        123, 'GERMANY',
        124, 'SPAIN',
        ...
        COUNTRY_CODE) as COUNTRY,
    Column2,
    Column3
FROM countrytable;
```